# Tomcat virtual host shows blank page

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I've been trying to configure tomcat for multiple domains and everything I have tried was unsuccessful.

I added this to /etc/tomcat7/server.xml

```
<Host name="www.mysite.com" appBase="webapps/mysite"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  <Alias>mysite.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

and I created the folder /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/mysite

Whenever I go to my domain all I get is a blank page. What am I doing wrong here? I am running Debian 7

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a change just to test if `www.mysite.com/mysite` works.

What I can get working is

```
<Host name="www.mydocs.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Alias>mydocs.com</Alias>
```

Here the appBase points to the `webapps` folder - but if I use appBase as `webapps/mysite` then I get the blank page.

In this case you probably need to try the `Context` element to define docbase to your app